# What does "if you treat her otherwise" mean in the following paragraph?

Tags: meaning-in-context

This account is my new account, because i can't remember my old account (sorry about this and i hope admin will not delete my post). Now i'm translating a book about women for a male client, named "The Manual: What Women Want and How to Give It to Them", and i posted my question [**here**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/365006/can-you-help-me-to-understand-the-highlighted-confusing-paragraph-in-this-photo), but i can't receive the question that is reasonable for me. In the book, i has a confusing paragraph that i posted on photo. Can you help me to understand the highlighted sentence, especially the expression "if you treat her otherwise"?. Thank you[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gmu4i.png)

Comment: Frankly, I've read your excerpt several times and each time the highlighted sentence stumped me. It's very unclear.

Comment: I think the emboldened part expands as follows: "...you are disrespecting her **if you treat her as though her value lies in her sexual exclusivity**."

Comment: @user2684291. Can you explain more clearly? I think "hence" in this sentence means " because they are not supposed to enjoy sex as much as males do or that the value of females lies in their sexual exclusivity", so "if you treat her otherwise" will mean "if you regard her in a way that is contrary to the belief that a female’s value lies in her sexual exclusivity". Why do you think "if you treat her otherwise" mean " if you treat her as though her value lies in her sexual exclusivity"

Comment: Let `X` := "you disagree with the notion that a female's value lies in her sexual exclusivity", then the sentence translates to, as I construe it, "...and if `X`, then you are disrespecting her if you do `not X`." What I wrote as the explanation is `not X`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is

> What is the **otherwise**?

The premise is

> 1) Women have value if they are sexually exclusive.
>   2) Being in pornography is nonexclusive, anyone can look.
>   3) A woman in pornography deserves less respect.

For the last bit, it is easier if stated in the positive not the negative

> 4) If you agree that a woman's value is in her sexual exclusivity, then
>   5) looking at pornography is disrespectful of women.

conversely

> If you disagree that a woman's value is in her sexual exclusivity, then
>   looking at pornography is respectful of women.

It is a circular argument, but the argument is that if one is a feminist then pornography is alright.